# Recommended practices for none grouped columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    s.siteid,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN si.Modified > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedMonth1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN si.Modified <= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND si.Modified > DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedMonth2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN su.Type = 'Member' THEN 1 END) AS MembersCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN su.Type = 'Owner' THEN 1 END) AS OwnersCount
FROM
    sites s
LEFT JOIN 
    ScannedItems si ON si.SiteId = s.SiteId
LEFT JOIN 
    SiteUsers su ON su.SiteId = s.SiteId
GROUP BY 
    s.SiteId
```

Now I have more columns (Url) I would like to add from the sites table. Now I can add the columns to the group by like:

```
SELECT
    s.siteid,
    s.Url,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN si.Modified > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedMonth1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN si.Modified <= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND si.Modified > DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedMonth2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN su.Type = 'Member' THEN 1 END) AS MembersCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN su.Type = 'Owner' THEN 1 END) AS OwnersCount
FROM
    sites s
LEFT JOIN 
    ScannedItems si ON si.SiteId = s.SiteId
LEFT JOIN 
    SiteUsers su ON su.SiteId = s.SiteId
GROUP BY 
    s.SiteId, s.Url
```

Or could I just do a `MAX(s.Url)` in the `SELECT`? Is there any recommended practice for this?

Comment: Your code is fine. The only reason that you should try `max(s.Url)` is if you experience performance issues.

Comment: What isn't working with the column being in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` or in a `MAX`?

Comment: Both is working. My question is one approach to be preferred over the other? Is there any rules when to use one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, `siteid` is the primary key of `sites`, so `url` is a functionnaly dependent column. If so, you can just add it to the `select` clause and to the `group by` clause; the results of the query will not be altered, you will just get an additional column in the resultset.

Let me pinpoint, however, that I am suspicious about the query logic to start with. If there are multiple matches in both `scanneditems` and `siteusers` for a given `site`, the join will multiply the rows, and the reults of the `count()` will be off. I find that it would be safer to pre-aggregate in subqueries. Here is an example using lateral joins:

```
select s.siteid, si.*, su.*
from sites s
cross apply (
    select 
        count(case when si.modified > dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) then 1 end) as modifiedmonth1,
        count(case when si.modified <= dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) and si.modified > dateadd(month, -2, getdate()) then 1 end) as modifiedmonth2
    from scanneditems si
    where si.siteid = s.siteid and si.modified <= dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
) si
cross apply (
    select
        count(case when su.type = 'member' then 1 end) as memberscount,
        count(case when su.type = 'owner' then 1 end) as ownerscount
    from siteusers su 
    where su.siteid = s.siteid and su.type in ('member', 'owner')
) su
```

There is no more aggregation in the outer query, and you can add any `site` column that you like to the outer `select`.

This query would take advantage of the following indexes:

```
scanneditems(siteid, modified)
siteusers(siteid, type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine as it is if you get correct results.

If you plan to add more columns from `sites` to the query, I would suggest separate aggregation in each of the tables `ScannedItems` and `SiteUsers` and join the results to `sites`, from which you can select as many columns as you want, so there is no need for any further aggregation:

```
WITH 
  si AS (
    SELECT SiteId,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Modified>DATEADD (month, -1 ,GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedMonth1,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Modified<=DATEADD (month, -1 ,GETDATE()) AND Modified>DATEADD (month, -2 ,GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) AS ModifiedMonth2
    FROM ScannedItems
    GROUP BY SiteId
  ),
  su AS (
    SELECT SiteId,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Type='Member' THEN 1 END) AS MembersCount,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Type='Owner' THEN 1 END) AS OwnersCount
    FROM SiteUsers
    GROUP BY SiteId
  )
SELECT s.siteid, s.Url, s.othercolumn, ....
       si.ModifiedMonth1, si.ModifiedMonth2,
       su.MembersCount, su.OwnersCount
FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN si ON si.SiteId = s.SiteId
LEFT JOIN su ON su.SiteId = s.SiteId
```